# How to leave the logo only on the first form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I use the following command in android for the logo to stay on top, of the problem and that in all my forms the logo keeps showing up. I want it to appear only on the main page, how can I do this?

```
//Toolbar.axml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

//MainActive
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one Activity that you need to show the logo on, then I would set the visibility of the ImageView to `gone` by default and in your main Activity set it to visible (`ViewStates.Visible`).

Add an `id` and set the `visibility` to `gone`:

```
~~~
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:src="@drawable/mel"/>
~~~
```

Then in your main Activity:

```
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
var imageView = ToolbarResource.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

Comment: ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
            imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

Comment: @José `NullReferenceException` what object is null? you need to debug your code